# Spring databinder reusing

Tags: spring, databinder

I'm creating few objects in loop using DataBinder. I wonder if it is possible to reuse DataBinder object instead of create it each time.

Is it possible?

Now I have:

```
while (condition) {
    obj = new MyObj();
    DataBinder db = new DataBinder(obj,"my obj");
    db.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatParam), false));
    // set up binder with some editors etc.
    objectvalues = getValues();
    MutablePropertyValues mpv = new MutablePropertyValues();
    for (int i=0;i<fieldNames.length;i++){
        mpv.add(StringUtils.trim(fieldNames[i]), objectvalues[i]);
    }
    db.bind(mpv);
    // do something with obj...
}
```

I'd like to have (*this is imagination only...*):

```
obj = new MyObj();
DataBinder db = new DataBinder(obj,"my obj");
db.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatParam), false));
// set up binder with some editors etc.
MutablePropertyValues mpv = new MutablePropertyValues();
for (int i=0;i<fieldNames.length;i++){
    mpv.add(StringUtils.trim(fieldNames[i]), "empty value");
}
while (condition) {
    objectvalues = getValues();
    for (int i=0;i<fieldNames.length;i++){
        mpv.setPropertyValueAt(objectvalues[i], i);
    }
    db.bind(mpv);
    objCopy = obj.clone();
    // do something with objCopy...
}
```

Is any safe way to do it like that, to not waste memory and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, target object in `DataBinder` is final, if you want to bind on another object you are forced to create a new `DataBinder` for it.